# Why did the TX from T3: Rise of the Machines change form?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

Why, on approaching Katherine Brewster, did the TX turn into its default form?  It could have kept her fiance's form long enough to kill her when she was within range.

Answer (score 6):

### Sequence of events

- The TX arrives at the graveyard in a cop car with 2 dead cops in the front seat.
  One is slumped against the drivers window, and the passenger window is shattered.  The TX is impersonating the fiance at this point.
- Kate has escaped from the 2 madmen and is approaching the car.
- The TX exits the car looking like her fiance, smiling.  But she pauses, *noticing something amiss.*
- As he approaches, she continues to walk ahead, slowly, hesitating and showing confusion.
- **Then** the TX changes back and powers up the energy weapon.
- The T101 blasts her & they escape again.

### Theories based on that

1. The primary weapon could not be powered up unless the TX was in default or 'bare metal' mode.
   That is why she only rarely attempted to use disguises.
2. It was uncertain of Kate's continued devotion to her fiance, especially when she showed hesitation &
   confusion in seeing the TX in that form.  Or perhaps it guessed that its cover was blown and felt that
   changing to the default form no longer mattered.

Personally I don't much like either theory.  The first is based on the presumption that the TX was most lethal in default form.  The TX never uses the primary weapon while in other forms, but that does not prove it cannot.

The second is based on psychology that would be hard for a human to determine, let alone a terminator.  And the visible evidence was that she was indeed continuing to walk closer to the TX.  Of course, you might also wonder why the TX did not simply pull out a gun and kill her from a distance, or run her down using the cop car..

Comment: The above does not make sense when answering my question because I did not ask whether or not engagement really did not matter. Regardless, it could be seen through extrapolation that if the TX kept her fiance's form, they would have hugged and she would have been killed.

Then again, you may be saying that it was never destined that she should have been killed because then it would not have worked out to where she would have died her normal death, after she had met John Conner in the future.

Comment: My memory of the movie was faulty & I completely forgot the TX visiting the apartment and the subsequent shenanigans.  After watching it again and observing that scene very closely, I have come up with two alternate theories, neither of which is good.  See edit.

Comment: Those two answers seem to be a bit better. It's totally cool. I am glad that you spent the extra time to view the scene to better answer the question and I definitely appreciate that. It would seem that the movie itself had some sort of loophole at that point. Whatever theory may be true though, we know one thing for sure. The reason why neither John nor Katherine were killed was because then the movie would be over and there would be no way to further elaborate on it. Chalk this one up to the messed up Terminator series from what was once James Cameron's work.

Answer (score 2):

The film's [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines_(novel)) offers a slight clue. It's not definitive, but based on Kate Brewster's *reaction* to the change, it's certainly possible that the T-X changed forms **in order to frighten her**, thus gaining an additional psychological advantage when she launches her attack.

> *T-X moved toward Kate, morphing, as he seemed to glide over the grass,
> back into the persona of Nancy Nebel in the rust-colored Gucci leather
> suit.*
>
> *Her right arm was changing into the plasma weapon, and Kate
> stopped in midstride.  **This was the same monster from the pet clinic.
> The one who had killed Betsy. The one who had nearly killed them all.***
>
> *"No" Kate moaned, stepping back Was there no end to this insanity?*
>
> *T-X raised her plasma weapon, the blue glow surrounding her arm as the
> unit came to a full charge.*

No explanation is offered why it didn't just stay as Scott until it was in a position to stab her other than the fact that the T-X demonstrates distinct traits of both recklessness and impatience.